# Roll back both on local branch and master branch?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

How can I roll back to the last commit both local branch and master branch?

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at e861a3e Added push menu label.

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

It asks me to pull. But if I pull I wiil get the same commit back from the master branch.

I made a mistake in my code and I have committed and pushed. So I need to roll back the commit and the push.

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: You could force push local: `git push --force origin master` after you did the reset on the local branch.

Comment: You can read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should **not** remove commits from remote. In general you should **not** modify remote history. Someone could have started making changes on top of that commit.

Usually it's much better to **revert** a commit. A revert is a new commit that undoes all the changes contained in the reverted commit. You revert a commit with

```
git revert COMMIT_HASH
```

Then you push this commit as every other commit, and the changes of `COMMIT_HASH` are gone.

Before you do this, you have to undo your commit deletion on your local branch. You can do this with

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```